# Iterating through each array to calculate z-score

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays and I need to calculate the z-score for each array i.e. z-score for each row in that array of arrays.

My code:

```
for x in train_image_resize:
    train_image_resize_mean = scipy.stats.zscore(x)
```

> Error:
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:2253: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide return (a - mns) / sstd

If I do `scipy.stats.zscore(train_image_resize)`, then it calculates the z-score of each number in the array of arrays. However, I wish to calculate one z-score for each array.

Answer (score 0):

This would indicate that you are dividing by zero, i.e. that the sample standard deviation vanishes; for example:

```py
In [5]: scipy.stats.zscore([1, 1])
..\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:2315: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  return (a - mns) / sstd
Out[5]: array([nan, nan])
```

Comment: train_image_resize is the array of arrays. If i choose x in the train_image_resize, then how the code is making standard deviation zero.

Comment: If `x` only contains one distinct element, i.e. is a constant array, then that's what would happen.

Comment: This is the array: array([[ 95, 101,  99, ..., 116, 118,  96],
       [ 91,  92,  91, ..., 100,  90,  81],
       [ 87,  70,  72, ...,  80,  84,  90],
       ...,
       [133, 102, 121, ..., 130, 131, 111],
       [118, 117, 115, ..., 100, 100, 109],
       [ 74,  89,  92, ..., 126, 116, 106]], dtype=int64)

Comment: That output is truncated, so chances are the potential constant array is hidden in the `...`.